# Filter out certain logs from logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I'm using a 3rd party library that currently has some bug that constantly spews out a certain error message in logcat. Sometimes this happens multiple times per second. The text is always the same.
This makes debugging really hard as it:

- makes logcat scroll really fast
- makes it hard to find relevant logs
- fills up the whole logfile, deleting older logs (often just a minute old or so)

I assume this is also not good for performance but that's not the real issue.

While waiting for a fix in the library, **I would like to filter out this specific error message from logcat. So that I can see everything except this one error and it's stacktrace.**

**Can I filter this out using Android Studio?
If it is filtered, will the messages still get deleted quickly if the file is full?**

I know how to disable logs using proguard. I would like to have a solution without proguard since in this development version proguard is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining previous two answers with some checking of the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#outputFormat) gave me a good solution to see the logs that I want.

```
adb -d logcat -v threadtime | grep -w 4451 | grep -v 4488
```

`-d` so I can limit the output to the logs from my currently connected device while I still have emulators running in the background.
`-v threadtime` So that I can see the `Process ID` and `Thread ID` and timestamp.
`grep -w 4451` With 4451 being the Process ID. This makes sure I see only logs from my app.
`grep -v 4488` With 4488 being the Thread ID of the error message I want to filter out. This removes all lines with the specified Thread ID. This works because in my case the error message only comes in a separate thread.

Now I can see all the logs from my application without all the noise from the error in the library.
(Not confirmed but I believe the logs will still disappear when the log file is full because of the constant stream of error messages from the library.)

This is a command line solution, so it is still not an optimal solution using logcat in android studio. But it does perfectly work from the Terminal tab in Android Studio.

Answer (score 6):

To filter out unwanted `logcat` messages in `Android-Studio` you can use regex negative look-arounds:
eg. to filter out all Lines containing `zip`:

1. In `Logcat-Window` click `filter-dropdown menu`
2. select `"edit Filter Configuration"`
   put following code in `Log Message` field: `^((?!zip).)*$`
   and select `regex` to the right of the field.

I found this way of using regex in the following post: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word/406408#406408?newreg=36112fdbf0a646f3a0792718dc5b4c98)

Answer (score 1):

Using adb from the command line you can easily filter out specific tags. I have a script called `logcat_filtered` that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ANDROID_LOG_TAGS='AlarmManager:S daemonapp:S WifiStateMachine:S SensorService:S SignalStrength:S dalvikvm:S Exchange:S ProcessStatsService:S GCoreUlr:S dalvikvm-heap:S chromium:S DMCFaceEngine:S SmartFaceService:S SecCamera-JNI-Cpp:S Camera_HAL:S STATUSBAR-BatteryController:S STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar:S STATUSBAR-NetworkController:S Camera:S lights:S BatteryService:S IconMerger:S LockPatternUtils:S' adb logcat
```

This gets rid of a lot of annoying log output that I'm not interested in.

A simpler solution, again from the command line, is to use grep:

```
adb logcat | grep -v dontwanttoseethisstring
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You can add a tag to specific logs when creating them:

```
Log.i("MyTag", msg);
```

and in logcat filter them ike this:

> Tag:MyTag

2- To filter all logs from only your app filter the logcat by typing :

> app:com.example.yourappname

**EDIT:**
Due to the comments:

3- To filter logs created by a thread, at run time find a log that you want to filter same logs. See the TID column and filter the logcat with TID (Thread ID)

Note that every time that your app is run again , you should do this again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that doesn't help me. The logs are generated by a third party library. I don't want to filter them like that. I want to see every log EXCEPT that one from the library (which is 13 separate lines btw)

Comment: May you find the processID or ThreadID at run time and filter it?

Comment: That might be interesting. If you could enlighten me on that that would be great! =)